# Происхождение слов телега и подвода

Tags: этимология

«Також для вывоза всего того и багажу армейского имеют все потребные подводы и телеги до границы от жителей бесспорно и безденежно даны быть [Ништадтский мирный договор между Россией и Швецией (1721)]».

Из цитаты следует, что в 1721 под словами «подвода» и «телега» подразумевались неравноценные (нетождественные) колесные повозки для перемещения грузов и м.б. людей. В чем заключалась разница между ними?
Как произошли слова «подвода» и «телега»? Кого и в чем подвела «подвода»? Неужели родная наша телега – родственница заграничным штучкам наподобие телепатии и телекинеза?
Если «тележку» приспособить для перевозки пассажиров и их багажа, а ее название произносить слегка искажая, может ли получиться «дилижанс»?

Answer (score 1):

**1) Телега**

Слово в этимологическом отношении неясное. У Черных большая статья на эту тему, но он скорее критикует разные версии. Вывод он делает такой: можно считать, что э**то старое (с древнерусской поры) заимствование в Востока.** Например, алт. тегелик – колесо, тегерик – круг, сравнить: колесо – колесница.

**2) Подвода**

**ПОДВОДА**  Повозка, телега для перевозки грузов, двигающаяся конной тягой.

У Даля: https://slovar.cc/rus/dal/564531.html

Подвода жен. зимняя или летняя **повозка с лошадью**, телега, сани, **особ. выставленные от земства**.

Также:

архан. **подвода и подводка**, **тропинка** в лесу, подводящая промышленника и лесника к жилью;

**Подвод**, что подведено: введенное в стену бревно или венец; перекладина, брус на стойках, подведенный под потолок, или свод.

Исходя из этих примеров, можно предположить, что подвода – это изначально **средство для решения конкретной задачи**; обычно подводы давались местными властями для перевозки грузов  определенного назначения (или людей). В этом случае подвода – это **комплект**, то есть повозка (телега) и лошади.

Comment: Мне кажется, что в слове "подвода" корень "воз". Мы же вызываем такси, что бы нас "подвезли". Заниматься "извозом", - "подвозить" грузы / пассажиров.

Comment: У Даля подвода рассматривается в статье для глагола "подводить" .Там же: Под вести подводы не надо￼. Таким образом, подвода  (лошадь с повозкой) - это то, что подали  (подвели, привели) под какой-то груз.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что, когда нужно было впрячь лошадь, говорили:"Давай, подводи!". Лошадь - лошадь,а сама телега и получилась - подвода, т. е. та, к которой подводят.